# Regex - For each line: Line starts with > until <

Tags: javascript, regex

How I can get all codes that starts with (at the beginning of the line) > until < ?

This is a example:

```
>foo// comment

>bar i< // <---
>foobar< // comment > code example<fo}
  >  off < bad formated line
```

I need this:

```
bar i
foobar
```

Comment: What language are you using? A _generic_ way, but taking the symbols is `^>[^<]*<`

Comment: Javascript. I'm very new in Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this snippet:

```js
var content = [
    ">foo// comment",
    "",
    ">bar i< // <---",
    ">foobar< // comment > code example<fo}",
    "  >  off < bad formated line"
];

content.filter(function(text) {
    var result = text.match(/^>[^<]*</);
    if (result) {
        document.write(result[0] + '<br>');
        document.write(result[0].slice(1, -1) + '<br><br>');
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I added a myString.split('\n') to my content to make the array and your code works great :D

Comment: @Gohchi. As you have all content in a variable, you can just use `var arrayResult = myString.match(/^>[^<]*</gm);`.. Anyways, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take the comment from Washington Guedes and explain it here:

```
^>[^<]*<
```

- `^` at the beginning of the expression matches the start of the line
- `>` is what you want to find at the beginning of the line
- `[^<]*` matches everything that is not a `<` character zero or more times
- `<` matches the `<` character at the end of your string of interest
- `([^<]*)` to my example below, I have added brackets that indicate a group in the regular expression.

here is how this could look like in javascript:

```
var myString = "your input goes here";
var myRegexp = /^>([^<]*<)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
```

You can find information on how to use RegExp objects on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: "matches everything that is not a `<` character", zero or more times

Comment: Thanks for the info. The return is something rare. An array of two results: [ ">foo// comment↵↵>bar i<","foo// comment↵↵>bar i<"]

Answer (score 0):

### general regex

```
/^>([^<\n]*)</gm
```

### JavaScript code

```
var re = /^>([^<\n]*)</gm; 
var str = '>foo// comment\n\n>bar i< // <---\n>foobar< // comment > code example<fo}\n  >  off < bad formated line';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

### snipest

https://regex101.com/r/kM7nU3/1

Comment: It works :D I want to get the content only. I added a **(?=<)** at end, but I have no idea what is for after > (sorry for my english n_n')

Comment: `m[0]` - line, `m[1]` - content only

Comment: thanks! It works perfect